# issue in moving image across y axis in android

Tags: android

I am relatively new to android and very much new to animation. I am trying to move image from bottom of screen to top of screen.

I am using below code

```
ImageView sun = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(view.getId());
AnimatorSet sunSet = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.sun_swing);
sunSet.setTarget(sun);
sunSet.start();
```

and xml file is as shown below

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:ordering="sequentially" >
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="8000"
    android:propertyName="y"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:valueTo="-200"
    android:valueFrom="800"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

Image moving from 800 to -200 but in case screen resolution is more it is not coming from bottom. How to dynamically set values according to different display.

Answer (score 0):

use this animation to move view from bottom to top in android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="100" />
```